# Need help understanding MVVM model WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have made small C# application for displaying Database in WPF DataGrid. Everything works fine but as I have two windows in application, I need to load Database separately to both of them. I would like to load it once and be able to filter data separately in a different way in two different windows. I have understood that the right way to proceed is to create MVVM model?

With help from this website I have managed to build what I have at the moment, however it is not functioning correct. I don't understand how data load should be triggered correct in MVVM model to get values on DataGrid?

---

**Here is my working solution (not MVVM):**

C#

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace DB_inspector_FilterTest
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

                DataGrid1.ItemsSource = await GetDataAsync();

                ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private Task<DataView> GetDataAsync()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {

                string connectionStringDE = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=DB123;dbq=@DBFSSE;Uid=ADMIN;Pwd=123;";

                string queryStringDE = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTB,CORPORATION,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";

                string connectionStringFR = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=DB123;dbq=@DBFSFI;Uid=ADMIN;Pwd=123;";

                string queryStringFR = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTB,CORPORATION,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";

                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
                // using-statement will cleanly close and dispose unmanaged resources i.e. IDisposable instances
                using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionDE = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringDE))
                {
                    dbConnectionDE.Open();
                    OdbcDataAdapter dadapterDE = new OdbcDataAdapter();
                    dadapterDE.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringDE, dbConnectionDE);

                    dadapterDE.Fill(dataTable);

                }
                using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionFR = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringFR))
                {
                    dbConnectionFR.Open();
                    OdbcDataAdapter dadapterFR = new OdbcDataAdapter();
                    dadapterFR.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringFR, dbConnectionFR);

                    var newTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
                    dadapterFR.Fill(newTable);

                    dataTable.Merge(newTable);

                }

                return dataTable.DefaultView;

            });
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> _conditions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        private void UpdateFilter()
        {
            try
            {
                var activeConditions = _conditions.Where(c => c.Value != null).Select(c => "(" + c.Value + ")");
                DataView dv = DataGrid1.ItemsSource as DataView;
                dv.RowFilter = string.Join(" AND ", activeConditions);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void NameSearch_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string filter = NameSearch.Text;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
                _conditions["name"] = null;
            else
                _conditions["name"] = string.Format("NAME Like '%{0}%'", filter);
            UpdateFilter();
        }

        private void ActiveCustomer_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ActiveCustomer.IsChecked == true)
            {
                _conditions["active"] = string.Format("ACTIVE Like '%{0}%'", "1");
                UpdateFilter();
            }
            else
            {
                _conditions["active"] = null;
                UpdateFilter();
            }
        }

        private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (OnlyFIandSE.IsChecked == true)
            {
                _conditions["onlyfrandde"] = string.Format("NRO Like '2%' OR NRO Like '3%'");
                UpdateFilter();
            }
            else
            {
                _conditions["onlyfrandde"] = null;
                UpdateFilter();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DB_inspector_FilterTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DB database inspector v.0.0.01" Height="600" Width="1000" Icon="logo_icon-small.jpg" Background="White">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" Margin="0,103,0,0" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF38853F"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="NameSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="22,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="437" TextChanged="NameSearch_TextChanged"/>
        <Button Content="Load" Margin="640,41,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Background="#FF55B432" Width="66" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="992" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label Content="Customer name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="22,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="ActiveCustomer" Content="Active" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="486,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" Click="ActiveCustomer_Click_1"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="Only" Content="Leave only good" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="486,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
        <Image Margin="856,0,22,520" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Source="logo_small.jpg" Height="27"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**MVVM:**

C#

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DB_inspector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand myCommand => new RelayCommand(obj =>
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionStringDE = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=DB123;dbq=@DBFSSE;Uid=ADMIN;Pwd=123;";

                string queryStringDE = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTB,CORPORATION,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";

                string connectionStringFR = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=DB123;dbq=@DBFSFI;Uid=ADMIN;Pwd=123;";

                string queryStringFR = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTB,CORPORATION,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";

                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
                // using-statement will cleanly close and dispose unmanaged resources i.e. IDisposable instances
                using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionDE = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringDE))
                {
                    dbConnectionDE.Open();
                    OdbcDataAdapter dadapterDE = new OdbcDataAdapter();
                    dadapterDE.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringDE, dbConnectionDE);

                    dadapterDE.Fill(dataTable);

                }
                using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionFR = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringFR))
                {
                    dbConnectionFR.Open();
                    OdbcDataAdapter dadapterFR = new OdbcDataAdapter();
                    dadapterFR.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringFR, dbConnectionFR);

                    var newTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
                    dadapterFR.Fill(newTable);

                    dataTable.Merge(newTable);

                }

                _ = dataTable.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        });

        private bool _allowUIChanges = true;
        public bool AllowUIChanges
        {
            get => _allowUIChanges;
            set
            {
                _allowUIChanges = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AllowUIChanges));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsReadOnlyDataGrid));
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsReadOnlyDataGrid
        {
            get => !_allowUIChanges;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

        public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DB_inspector.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DB database inspector" Height="595.404" Width="1005.571">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnlyDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" Width="998" Margin="0,98,0,0" >
        </DataGrid>
        <Image Height="41" Margin="0,21,10,0" Width="141" Source="logo_small.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Go" Command="{Binding myCommand}" Width="80" Height="30" Margin="48,42,870,492"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What is working and what isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you might be coming from WinForms background. I had same issues when transfering to WPF. I will give you an example following your code so you can better understand what is going on.

You were on right track when instantiating a model but you forgot to assign the model to the `DataContext` of the main window. `DataContext` is exactly what it says. Data context of the window and in your case it is `ViewModel` class. Assign it in the `MainWindow` constructor.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

From now on you can use normal bindings in the XAML which is what WPF is mostly about.

Now you have to work on your model a bit. First of, you have to change the command to be a property and not field. It is enough to define an empty property and assign it a `Command` in the `ViewModel` constructor.

```
public ICommand Load { get; }
```

For simplicity sakes I added a simplest of collections as a property.

```
private List<string> m_items;
public List<string> Items
{
    get => m_items;
    set
    {
        m_items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
    }
}
```

Also, I can see you have started to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. This is a most crucial interface in WPF and I suggest to read up a bit on it. A correct implementation in you case should be as follows:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
}
```

Finally in the `ViewModel` constructor assign the `Command` to `Load` property like so:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    Load = new RelayCommand(obj =>
    {
        try
        {
            // Load your stuff here
            Items = new List<string>() { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Your XAML is very simple in this case. I have added only the button and a grid.

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Load" Command="{Binding Load}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, the data grid is bound to a property named Items(our collection) and Buttons Command property is bound to a property called Load(our command). When user presses the button the command will be executed. The command sets property Items with a new collection and in turn the setter raises OnPropertyChanged that DataGrid subscribed to. This makes the Grid read the Items property and populate itself.

This is roughly how it's done. That being said, I suggest you read up a bit on WPF and how it works. I think it is much better than immediately try something this big and then ask for help. Usually these big examples don't get much attention.